# Jquery undefined is not an object (evaluating '$.ui.mouse')

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have **JqueryUI** and **Touch-punch** and in mobile device I get the error: `undefined is not an object (evaluating '$.ui.mouse')`.

I try to find why I get this error and I verify:

- First load JqueryUI and after this load touch punch.
- Only one Jquery is installed (2.2.4)

This only happen when I try to use touch-punch in **mobile device** not on laptop. (In laptop touch-punch is recognized and working. In mobile I think it's recognized but not working how should do it).

This is my script:

```
$('.touchtable').on('doubletap',function(e){ 
    mover(); 
}); 
function mover(){ 
    $("#tbodyproject").sortable({ 
    items: "> tr", 
    appendTo: "parent", 
    helper: "clone", 
    placeholder: "placeholder-style", 
    containment: ".table", 
    start: function(event, ui) { 

    var cantidad_real = $('.table thead tr th:visible').length; 
    var cantidad_actual = $(this).find('.placeholder-style td').length; 

    if(cantidad_actual > cantidad_real){ 
    var cantidad_a_ocultar = (cantidad_actual - cantidad_real); 

    for(var i = 0; i <= cantidad_a_ocultar; i++){ 
    $(this).find('.placeholder-style td:nth-child('+ i +')').addClass('hidden-td'); 
    } 
    } 

    ui.helper.css('display', 'table') 
    }, 
    stop: function(event, ui) { 
    ui.item.css('display', '') 
    }, 
    update: function( event, ui ) { 
    let newOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray'); 
    $.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url:'/admin/projects/updateOrder', 
    data: {ids: newOrder} 
    }) 
    .done(function( msg ) { 
    location.reload(); 
    }); 
} 
}).disableSelection(); 
}
```

The script is to be possible to drag and drop rows and also be available to scroll without a drag. So when user make double tap then function start to works and be possible to make drag and drop.

In computer is working, in mobile or ipad not.

If inside `function mover()` I put a `console.log` in console I will se the log but drag and drop it's not working.

How I should fix the error of undefined? I think if I fix the error script will work on mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

I have one file where I have `require('jqueryui');` and this file was loaded **after** `<script src="/cms/lib/jquerytouchpunch/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js"></script>`
I just change de order and looks like this in **`<head>`**

```
<script src="/assets/js/cms.js"></script>
<script src="/cms/lib/jquerytouchpunch/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js"></script>
```